# connection Google cloud datastore emulator

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud

I have installed google datastore emulator in my local machine along with it written a sample spring boot application .
**I can't  connection datastore emulator**

This is my application.properties config

```
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.project-id=project-id
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator-host=http://localhost:8081
```

by this config , I will throw Exception

```
The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator), you don't need credentials for running the application, so it might be that the [library](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp) doesn't know that.

However, if you want to try it providing credentials, once you have a service account created, then run in the shell the following:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH"
```

`KEY_PATH` you have to replace it with the path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#linux-or-macos).